# How do I mimic App Store.app UI

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, window, titlebar

I would like to mimic the App Store.app UI interface for an application I am currently toying with. I can place Custom View on the title bar but I am having trouble positioning the close/min/max buttons a little bit lower. In general, the effect that I would like to achieve is for the title bar to be padded on the top and the bottom, making it look bigger and the window buttons vertically centered, just like the way it is with the App Store.app application.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're going to have to simply subclass NSWindow and use a borderless style, then handle drawing the window frame yourself.  There's a lot more useful information on that over at [CocoaDev](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?BorderlessWindow) (including a link to an example of this provided by Apple).  To handle the close/minimize/zoom buttons, you might want to just set up a few buttons that draw those (and respect system color settings).